# Testflight and expo go notification not working

Tags: firebase, react-native, apple-developer, expo-go, expo-notifications

i'm receiving issue while using expo go and Testfligt. My notifications are not showing on testflight devices, but when i build apk file, it works fine.

I have installed everything and set up, firebase, certificates, etc..

i tried everything, changing "distribution": "store" in eas json, changing keys and certificates, everything, but it doesn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, the problem was that p8 file was not linked correctly, I linked it manually through the terminal and now it works :) –